# Little hard translation from Polish to English "Someone waited but _not done_"?

Tags: phrase-request

I want to translate *ktoś nie doczekał się (na X) i zrezygnował* (== "someone was waiting [for X, and X didn't happen] and resigned").

I cannot find the right negation for *wait*; maybe there is no equivalent.

I found some translations that very close to what I want to say.

1. He did not live and resigned.
2. He did not wait and resigned.
3. He did not reach and resigned.

What translation is more valid and common?

I am not sure if I should say "He was waiting for order but he did not wait and resign."

What would a native speaker say?

---

Polish use **aspects** which not exist in English so it can not be translated without omit context or artificial syntax - I did not know that before.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect
http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspekt_(j%C4%99zykoznawstwo)

The most valid translation could be:
*Czekałem, ale nie doczekałem się i zrezygnowałem* == ugly *I waited, but waiting was not successful and I gave up* or shortly (small loose of context) *I waited and gave up*

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thanks for grammar fixes and reduction but you little too much change the content - it is good to keep more original meaning since you could change my personality too what I want to avoid :)

Comment: Chameleon, kiam has done a great work improving the question, indeed considering that the original version was so unclear that not all people could have understood what it was being asked here.

Comment: @Carlo_R. Sure that was very good in 90% percent but in 10% I loose some personality - especially in part where I am asking for help :)

Comment: I didn't change the meaning. Even if it would be understood, == doesn't mean "it translates as," "its literal translation is," or "its roughly equivalent of." It's not exactly clear what you mean with ==, nor if you would use === when you are showing the translation that perfectly match the original phrase. :)

Comment: Chameleon, yes, but don't forget that our motto is "VOTE EARLY, VOTE OFTEN", and you don't still have voted none of the answers you have got.

Comment: Chameleon, this is not a matter of personality coming through your writing: I cannot understand your question. What do you mean by "resign"? "He did not live" means he died; what exactly are you trying to say?

Comment: @Martha What is meaning of live in this context "She didn't live to see her grandchildren." or here wait "She didn't wait to see her grandchildren." - sometimes dictionaries are bad :)? I mean by "resign" == "give up (purchase) order".

Comment: Chameleon, what is "no done" meaning here? Perhaps, "whitout having results"? Please, help me in understanding the question better.

Comment: @Chameleon: In future, you should try to add anything that you feel was removed in an edit back to the revised post instead of rolling it back. Rolling back an edit should be reserved for vandalism edits and when the edit completely changes the meaning of the question. Most edits (particularly on ELL) are made to improve the quality or readability of the question for future readers who might also benefit from your question and the answers that are posted.

Comment: @Chameleon: are you asking how to say "I waited for my food and it was taking so long that I canceled the order and left"?

Comment: @horatio Thank you for the suggestion near but not the same in English there are: _czekać_ == _wait_ in Polish there is verbs done and not done - see we have _czekać_ == _wait (not done)_ _doczekać się_ == wait (done with success!) _nie doczekać się_ (done with failure!) - Polish is Slavic/Indoeuropean uses [Aspect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect) [Aspekt](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspekt_(j%C4%99zykoznawstwo)).

I want express what is near "I waited but gave up." but with more context (it could said in positive, negative or neutral depend on use "czekać", "doczekać").

Comment: @horatio This kind of **aspect** cannot be expressed easily I think so. You emulate this aspect with inclusion I waited for my food and **it was taking so long** that I canceled the order and left". wait + (**it was taking so long**) is very near "doczekać się" but mean "Czekałem, ale **trwało to za długo** i zrezygnowałem" - original was "Czekałem, ale **nie doczekałem się** i zrezygnowałem". **nie doczekałem się** means directly _waiting was not successful_ - looks artificially.

Comment: I translated the wiki link on 'Aspects' into English and tried to understand it. What it sounds like the article is saying is summed up in one sentence from it: "You can add a prefix to the present tense of a verb to make it future tense." So is what you're talking about a matter of *time*? You want the difference between 1) you used to be waiting then stopped 2) you're still waiting but might stop 3) you might wait in the future...  Is that your question?

Comment: Hi Chameleon, I just found out that you recently posted this question on ELU, then reposted it here. The answer you got over there answers your question, as you can see from similar answers that have been posted here. As RegDwight told you on ELU, there simply isn't a construct in English that matches the one you're looking for. You'll have to describe this another way ("in vain", as posted in answers, is probably the best.) Anyway, after conferring with ELU mods I'm closing this question. I hope the answers make sense to you now; feel free to comment on them if not. Thanks!

Comment: It is not this case: "You can add a prefix to the present tense of a verb to make it future tense.". I could add prefix to define if *verb is done with (success or failure)*. 1st example: _czekać_ == _wait_ (not know if done) _czekałem_ == _I waited_ (know if done! still not aspect use!). 2nd **Aspect!** _doczekać_ (all tense is possible!) == _wait_ (done with success) _Czekałem i doczekałem się_ (know that is done and *with success*! - past) _Czekam i doczekam się_ (know that is not done but I *predict success in future* - present) _Będę czekał i doczekam się_ (same as before - future).

Comment: *This case* show different semantics in English - this *aspect use* is specific to Polish/Slavic. I could say _I waited in vain_. What about positive form? - __I waited not in vain_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably say:

> Despite waiting [for three hours], the bus did not arrive.

or perhaps even better, you could use *in vain* (meaning *to no avail*)

> I waited [for the bus] in vain.

or more directly:

> He waited for the orders, but they never came.

(Note that in the final example, "orders" is used as in "military orders", not as in an order for food).

Comment: Meaning of "He waited for the orders, but they never came." != "He did not wait and resign.". Do you mean "He waited for the order, but they never came and resigned". Here "order" = "order for food".

Comment: @Chameleon: "Resign" (i.e. to quit one's job) is almost certainly not the word you wanted in that sentence.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. So better is "give up order" but "resign from position/job". What you think about "He did not wait and give up (from order confirmation/delivery)"?

Comment: @Chameleon: If you want to say that he **did** give up, you would use the past tense: *He did not wait. Instead he gave up*, or *He did not wait; he gave up*, or *He did not wait but instead gave up* or the simplest *[After a while,] he gave up waiting [for the order].*

Comment: @Chameleon: If you want to say that he **did not** give up (even though the order never came), you could say *He did not give up waiting for the order*, or more simply *He waited for the order to arrive in vain.*.

Comment: This translation Polish/English is hard - probably lack of some abstract meaning in English - it is impossible to do it. The best is **"He waited and gave up"** what you think about it? (Not want say "he did not give up" != Polish/"He did not wait/reach" in Polish is "wait done with success" = "doczekać się" and "wait done with failure" == "niedoczekać się" and common "czekać" == "wait"). Thank you for help.

Comment: @Chameleon: I would probably go with "He eventually gave up waiting"

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you are looking for:

> [***to give up***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/give+up) : a. To cease to do or perform: *gave up their search*.
>
> After waiting at the bus stop for three hours he finally *gave up* and went home.

Comment: I think that "resign" == "give up" could I treat you suggestion that "give up" is more often and common? What you think about "He did not wait and give up".

Comment: I think that in order to *give up* you have to have been doing something and then stop doing it.  So "He waited (for a time) and then gave up."  But if he did not wait at all (not even for a second) then he can't have given up.  Maybe in that case he might have "given up without trying."  In your case though, I think most people would just say, "He gave up waiting (and went home).

Comment: It is hard to translate it I want to express that "someone was waiting but it not finished with success and give up" - i.e. "He was waiting for order confirmation but _did not wait_" Maybe I should say "He was waiting and gave up" - it will loose less context.

Comment: "He was waiting for order confirmation but did not wait *long enough*."??

Answer (score 2):

First, to "resign" does not mean to stop waiting. To "resign" means that you held a job or an office and quit, or that you withdraw from a contest, such as a game of sports. That is, you can say, "Mr Jones resigned from his job as an accountant" or "Mrs Smith resigned from her senate seat" or "Southhampton resigned from the football match". But you can't say, "He resigned from waiting for the bus."

As Jim says, a common phrase for what you want is "gave up". "When the bus didn't arrive after four hours, Bob gave up and went home." I don't know a single word that means "not wait", but you can simply use a phrase including the word "not" or something of similar meaning. Like, "After four hours, he decided not to wait any longer." Or, "When no one showed up, he quit waiting."

There is a related meaning of "resigned" meaning "accepted something reluctantly" that might be appropriate here. For example, you can say "He was resigned to going bald". So you could say something like, "When the bus didn't arrive after four hours, he was resigned to the fact that it would never show up and so he went home." But that's fairly long and awkward.

Comment: Good hint with "resign" this Latin word is used differently than in Polish (my dictionaries has many errors:)) - should be _give up_ - In Polish we use _rezygnować_ ~ _resign_ to people and things _rezygnować_ ~ abandom, cancel, resign, ... - i.e. _rezygnacja_ could be _cancellation_ and _resignation_. Thanks for phrase "give up"!